# Title disappeared when button’s background color is gradient

Tags: swift, uibutton

**Here is my custom button:**

```
class GradientButton: UIButton {
    private var colors: [UIColor] = [.white]
    private var direction: GradientDirection = .leftToRight

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    init(colors: [UIColor], direction: GradientDirection) {
        self.init()

        self.colors = colors
        self.direction = direction
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gradientColorWith(bounds: self.bounds, colors: self.colors, direction: self.direction)
    }
}
```

**And gradient color:**

```
enum GradientDirection {
    case topToBottom         
    case leftToRight         
    case bottomToTop         
    case rightToLeft         
    case leftTopToRightBottom
    case leftBottomToRightTop
    case rightTopToLeftBottom
    case RightBottomToLeftTop
}
extension UIColor {
    static func gradientColorWith(bounds: CGRect, colors: [UIColor], direction: GradientDirection) -> UIColor {

        var cgColorArray: [CGColor] = []
        for color in colors {
            cgColorArray.append(color.cgColor)
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, true, 1)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return .white }
        context.saveGState();
        let colorSpace = colors.last?.cgColor.colorSpace
        let gradient = CGGradient.init(colorsSpace: colorSpace, colors: cgColorArray as CFArray, locations: nil)!

        var startPoint = CGPoint.zero
        var endPoint = CGPoint.zero

        let width = bounds.size.width
        let height = bounds.size.height

        switch direction {
        case .topToBottom:
            startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0)
            endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: height)
        case .leftToRight:
            startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0)
            endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: width, y: 0)
        case .bottomToTop:
            startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: height)
            endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0)
        case .rightToLeft:
            startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: width, y: 0)
            endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0)
        case .leftTopToRightBottom:
            startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0)
            endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: width, y: height)
        case .leftBottomToRightTop:
            startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: height)
            endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: width, y: 0)
        case .rightTopToLeftBottom:
            startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: width, y: 0)
            endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: height)
        case .RightBottomToLeftTop:
            startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: width, y: height)
            endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0)
        }

        context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: startPoint, end: endPoint, options: .drawsBeforeStartLocation)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        context.restoreGState()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return UIColor.init(patternImage: image)
    }

}
```

**It's work perfect with UILabel,however,title disappeared on UIButton:**

```
private lazy var gradientButton: GradientButton = {
    let gradientButton = GradientButton.init(colors: [UIColor.orange, UIColor.purple], direction: .leftToRight)
    gradientButton.setTitle("This is a Button", for: .normal)
    gradientButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    gradientButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
    return gradientButton
}()
```

So I wonder Why title disappeared?

How to solve it?

**Note:I say color,so do not tell me add a layer or inset a layer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your implementation of `layoutSubviews` is wrong. You never call `super` so the button never actually gets laid out.

Let's fix it:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gradientColorWith(bounds: self.bounds, colors: self.colors, direction: self.direction)
}
```

Let's test it:

```
let b = self.gradientButton
b.sizeToFit()
b.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
self.view.addSubview(b)
```

[image]

Comment: A small mistake waste my all day️.Thanks for your help.